# Why is this the output?

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

I've been doing some studying and I came across this piece of code:

```
(((lambda (y)
     (lambda (z) (+ z (- 2 y)))) 3) 5)
```

The output of this code is 4 but I'm not sure why. I see that 3 is assigned to 'y' and 5 is assigned to 'z' but I can't see why exactly.

I was thinking that the 3 would be assigned to 'z' first and then 5 to 'y' but it's the other way around. What steps does scheme/racket take to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. The most clear justification is to make a step by step evaluation of the expression:

**1. Substitute the value for y**

```
((lambda (z)
   (+ z (- 2 3)))
 5)
```

**2. Substitute the value for z**

```
(+ 5 (- 2 3))
```

**3. Determine the value of the 2nd parameter of +**

```
(+ 5 -1)
```

**4. The needed value is here.**

```
4
```

Comment: I understand that but why does 3 get subbed into y? I would think that 3 would be passed into y and then passed from y to z. Now, when we pass in 5 and 3 has already been subbed in for z, naturally, 5 is substituted for y.

Comment: What you have here is called a curry function and why it happens so is that even functions are values for Scheme, so you keep applying the basic rule then evaluate the lambda function for z, even though it accepts another function as parameter:
1. Make substitutions of effective value to obtain effective parameters
2. Evaluate the effective parameters

Answer (score 0):

First we should understand lambda structure. If you look below

( **(** lambda (var ...) body1 body2 ...**)**
expr ...)

For example ((lambda (y) (* y y) 3)==> 3 assing to y. then (* 3 3)==>9

If you look below

```
(  >((lambda (y)
       (lambda (z) (+ z (- 2 y))))  3)<   ....)
```

3 assing to y.

```
Then >(  ((lambda (y)
           (lambda (z) (+ z (- 2 y))))  3)   5)<
```

5 assing to z

I hope this solving can be understandable